# mysql, performance issue with FOR UPDATE query

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id,domain_name FROM domains WHERE test_stage=1 order by id LIMIT 200 FOR UPDATE
```

This is happening up to 500 times multithreaded within a second, so quite fast and it's overloading my database server sometimes.
I think it's got something to do with an internal state of mysql, usually it's handled quickly but sometimes it just builds up and up.

Server is mysql 5.5. (I wish I could use a newer one but it's not possible to upgrade)
I have an index on test_stage,id
test_stage is an enum with just a few entries, id is autoincrement integer with a few million entries.

Anyone has an idea how to do that sort of query faster?
I know later mysql servers allow to "skip" locked rows, sadly I am with 5.5.

The purpose is selecting a number of "jobs" for a multithreaded worker.

P.S.
The only reason why my server is not crashing is because I have a CPU check added. As soon as 10 cores are fully loaded it stops adding more threads.

Update:
The server is quite strong, 120GB memory (mostly for mysql) and it's far from being maxed out.

```
Item(s) coming in up to 10,000 times a second.
1-20,000 arrive in each batch.
The client threads are limited to 600 threads by php and additional logic (runs on apache).
The threading uses  PHP 7.2 on serverside .
max_connections = 1500
Processing one item takes, on average 1-2 ms when everything works fine.
The table domains is current 20MM rows; it is purged never 

CREATE TABLE `domains` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `test_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `website_seo` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `context` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_stage` enum('a','b','c','d','e','f') DEFAULT 'a',
  `type` enum('a','b','c','d','e','f') DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter_z` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter_a` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0' ,
  `counter_b` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0' ,
  `counter_c` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0' ,
  `info_a` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `info_b` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extrapolate_a` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `extrapolate_c` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extrapolate_int` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0' ,
  `max_successful` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter_successful` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeout_counter_successful` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `domain_name` (`domain_name`),
  KEY `domain_name_test_time` (`domain_name`,`test_time`),
  KEY `test_time` (`test_time`),
  KEY `test_stage` (`test_stage`),
  KEY `counter_c_t` (`counter_c`,`test_time`),
  KEY `test_stage_test_time_counter_c` (`test_stage`,`test_time`,`counter_c`),
  KEY `test_stage_id` (`test_stage`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19437107 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I'd like to add: The issue is not apache or the number of threads, it's mysql not delivering the data.
My problem is that sometimes the "FOR UPDATE" select which selects a bunch of rows, and then updates them to be used  is delaying.
It can happen with 1000 rows being unprocessed, it can happen with 100,000 rows unprocessed.
After a while it suddenly works again, usually mysql can catch up and then you don't see anything in "processlist" anymore.
When it happens you see around 100-200 of them waiting and CPU spikes up to 10 cores (then the queue is locked from further additions)

Update:
I've had issues with similar problems before, the only solution then was to actually move all "open" requests into a temporary table and make the queue selections from there, synchronizing it back into the full table.
It's alot of additional work but then mysql is fast, I hate to do it again :(

Comment: How many cores do you have?  When things are working well, does it get 200 rows?  And how long does it take for a worker to deal with the 200 rows?

Comment: It's a 16 core 120GB server on AWS. It's not maxed out, the problem is the database taking too much time.  It just takes a few milliseconds after the 200 rows are returned.  
the amount of rows available depend on situation but I've seen the problem coming up at 1000 rows available and getting VERY BAD at 100,000 available. Mysql takes up to minutes to return them because 100+ are queued.

Comment: (Perhaps `test_stage=1` should really be `test_stage='a'`?)

Comment: I'm sorry, it's "a" yes. I had modified the names for NDA reasons

Comment: "a" -- sure.  And thanks for not obfuscating too much -- "test_stage ENUM" is a lot better than "col3 INT".

Comment: Here's my approach to high-speed ingestion and staging:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table  -- Maybe some of the ideas will work fo you.

Comment: I noticed one more issue which might be related to the problems. 
I have a duplicate key error inside the innodb table. Did an "optimize" and it failed due to a duplciate primary key.  
Hate it that the innodb engine is so unreliable, I'm now recreating the whole table

Answer (score 1):

My Mantra:  "Don't queue it, just do it."  Although I don't fully understand your design, I suspect that the problems would decrease if you simply processed the data as it comes in.

A Rule of Thumb:  If an item can be processed in less time than it takes to enqueue and dequeue it, then the Queue is wasting time.

To better discuss this, I need to understand all the dataflow.  For starters, fill in the blanks:

- Item(s) coming in ___ times a second.
- __ arrive in each batch.
- The client threads are limited to ____ threads by ______ (Apache/Tomcat/...).
- The threading uses _____ (PHP/Java/C#/...).
- `max_connections` = ____
- Processing one item takes, on average ___ ms.
- The table `domains` is current ____ rows; it is purged ______ (never/daily/immediately/...)  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE domains`.

**More**

Thanks for the update!

I gather that something else is changing `test_stage`, thereby effectively re-queueing rows?

Get rid of `KEY test_stage (test_stage)`, since it is redundant with two other indexes.

Change `KEY test_stage_id (test_stage, id)` to `KEY tid (test_stage, id, domain_name)` so that it is "covering".

One thought is to get rid of `id` and promote `domain_name` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  This avoids the need to deal with *two* unique keys.  Note that that would change the query and optimal index to

```
SELECT domain_name  FROM domains  WHERE test_stage=1 
    ORDER BY domain_name  LIMIT 200  FOR UPDATE
INDEX(test_stage, domain_name)
```

Another thought is to assign the "worker" threads to contiguous chunks of the table, based on the `PRIMARY KEY`.  That way, they should never (or at least rarely) collide over which rows to grab.  (I suspect this is the core of the issue.)

I assume your buffer_pool is big enough.  But if you would like a critique of the `VARIABLES`, please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES`.

Comment: I am updating my question

Comment: Hi, I used the "id" because I thought that a INT primary key would be handled faster in selects/updates than a domain key which can grow quite large in size.  I fear changing that isn't possible anymore due to too much code relying on the whole thing.  
Regarding changes: test_stage is only changed when the worker returns, so it's not touched after it was taken from queue (reserved).  

Are you sure that I should combine multiple indexes into one ? I thought that a query which only targets test_stage would do better with a dedicated (smaller) index than a large one that covers multiple q. ?

Comment: @John - a common myth.  There is a slight difference between a 4-byte INT and a few dozen bytes in a varchar.  However, there can be benefits in this (and other) situation that outweigh the common wisdom.  "Can't change" -- OK; I won't push for it. ...

Comment: Perhaps we need to see the "reservation" code and the "release" code.  I hope they are done in 'batch'; but beware of potential deadlocks.  It may be beneficial to 'sort' the ids in some consistent way. ...

Comment: The goal of the 3-column index was to make it "covering" -- That is all the columns in the `SELECT` are in the index's BTree, hence no need for reaching into the data's BTree.  (However, I don't know the details of the lock involved in `FOR UPDATE`.  ...

Comment: Is the 'batch' 'reserved' in one transaction, then 'released' in a separate one?  Or is there a single transaction that holds all the rows until all are ready to be released?  The former may like more than 200-row batches; the latter may prefer smaller batches.

Comment: Ok understand you! 
1)  LOCK queue - requests come in simultaneously so I used the FOR UPDATE to "quickly" get a bunch of IDs while preventing a race condition. So no other simultaneous accesses can take it.
I really wish direly I had "SKIP LOCKED" available :-(

I will try to make it covered by index, probably worth a test!

2)
The batch is indeed reserved quickly and released at another time from another session.

3) the actual batch size is not static, it depends on situation 20-300

Comment: @John - In _some_ situations, a single `UPDATE` can reserve the 200 items in autocommit mode.  This needs to be followed by a `SELECT` (again autocommit) to see what was grabbed.  Because the Update was atomic, all is well.  It avoids `FOR UPDATE`.  (I do not know if it would work for you, but ponder it.)

Comment: I'll consider that, it would need to add another column into the table (as to find the rows again that were updated), currently the update is "anonymous" as I only pass the IDs on.  

Do you have an idea why the FOR UPDATE uses test_stage_test_time_counter_c as an index ? Explain shows that. It doesn't seem to make much sense to use that index if there are specific indexes for the job available.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something. You say update followed by select. 
How would that work without writing some sort of identification IS into the updated rows ? 
If I make 500 updates (autocommit) and follow them with a SELECT, how could I be sure I select the own ones and not those of another parallel session ?

Comment: @John - The `UPDATE` would do that, but would not be able to provide all the ids; hence the `SELECT`.  Presumably the `UPDATE` would announce which client is 'reserving' the rows.  The `SELECT` would use that in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought.  
Regarding a covering index: I tried to create one but mysql is not using it in explain.
I tried a total minimal query (select ID from WHERE teststage LIMIT FOR UPDATE) and it still used a non primary index, also not teststage, it used the most complex index available for some strange reason.  
How can I know if it accesses the covering index or the main data during a query?

Comment: @John - As for the failure of the covering index -- it could any of several subtle things.  I would want to see the CREATE, EXPLAIN, etc to debug it.  That minimal query would prefer `(test_stage, id)` _which is identical to `(test_stage)`_

Comment: @John - When `EXPLAIN SELECT` says "Using index", it is "covering".  (Note: that is different than "Using index condition".)

Comment: Thanks for that, that's interesting.  
I tried test_stage,id  also test_stage and I tried them as UNIQUE key.  
Mysql doesn't like it and when using FORCE INDEX it actually reduces performance.  
Also last_query_cost is 142256 regardless which index I choose it's increddible high.  

From 20 million entries only 200,000 have that stage I want to test, but it seems to still create massive load.  I guess the only way to get around this is to actually use a secondary table and synchronize that

Comment: @John - Two more of by missives to read and ponder:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: @John Please post on pastebin.com or here, text results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; and if on *nix  ULIMIT -A report and  iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device.

Comment: @John - to go along with Wilson's request, please specify how many users you have so far.  The Status/Variables will need to be scaled up to get a fuller picture.

Comment: @john  On Jan 2, Rick James requested SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; to be posted.  If you wait 10 more days, there will be 10 more days of difficulties because we can not help you if you will not post requested detailed information to allow significant tuning suggestions.  We are trying to assist in your success.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't post it for NDA reasons.  It's full of things I am not permitted to show :(  
I solved the primary performance issues by upgrading the IOPS of storage to 16k and the server to 32 cores.  Expensive as *** but it can now handle the load.

Comment: @john Login as root and post results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_io%';  please.

Comment: @John Also, post results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%dirty%';  please.